# Server2Go not saving my database

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server2go

I am running server2go on my pc. This is a project for some of my clients. When i create a database in phpmyadmin using server2go the database is not saved. So each time I restart I have to create a database. How do i save the databse and what settings should I change on pms_config.ini file.
I have changed LocalMirror=0 and have MirrorFolder still empty.

Answer (score 2):

Server2Go was originally made to run off of a read-only CD, so the default setup will not save MySQL database changes. If you want to configure the server to keep all of your settings, you need to edit pms_config.ini so that LocalMirror=0, OverwriteLocalMirror=0, and DeleteDatabaseFiles=0.
Do this edit before you move on or you’ll lose all of your configurations. When you’re done, open up phpMyAdmin and log in as root without any password.